# Inserting a data into mysql from changeable number of form into corresponding columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have variable number of forms (name1,name2,name3...etc) and I need to put those data in corresponding colums (name1,name2, name3) so far I came with a this code:

```
if(isset($_POST["nombreItem"]) && count($_POST['nombreItem'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["ItemID"] as $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET `$_POST[ItemID]` = `$_POST[1]` ";

         mysql_query($query);
    }     

}
```

Whta Im doing wrong?

Comment: solution to my own questio:  if(isset($_POST["cantidad"]) && count($_POST['cantidad'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["cantidad"] as $key => $value) {
        $cantidad = $value;
  $value = $_POST["cantidad"][$key];
  $idItem = $_POST['hiddenField'][$key];
  $itemName = $_POST['hiddenName'][$key];
  $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET `fecha` = $timestamp, `idItem` = $idItem, `nombreItem` = $itemName, `cantidad` = $value";
  
         mysql_query($query);
    }     

}


echo "<br>";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You aren't connected to a database
2. The correct `INSERT` syntax is: `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ($val1, $val2)`
3. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.
4. Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to prevent against SQL injection (your code is vulnerable to this)

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I have it connected to the database, just I havent pass the code here. How do I match the columns name with corresponding form?

Comment: @Iznogud I can't magically know what your table columns are named. I'm guessing you've already set up the table on the database side?

Comment: Sure. I set up so the name of the colum match the id of the Item.

Comment: Okay, so the columns from your table go in the column list `(column1, column2)` and the values to put into the columns go after the `VALUES`

Comment: But thats the thing, I dont have the fix number of the forms. Im trying to make so the no mater the number of the forms.

Comment: The correct database design would accept `NULL`, and you do this with prepared statements. If the value passed from the form is empty, a `NULL` will be used for that column

Answer (score 0):

Use `PDO` or `mysqli` to `CRUD` your tables. 
Use sanitization of inputs received from users in order to avoid [SQL INJECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
Use [PHP sanitize filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) in order to increase your databse security,  paired with `PDO`.
Better normalize your tables,  it's not a good practice to have many columns but just fill a few of them.  A table with `NULL` fields as a common practice, indicates a mediocre database architecture and poor performance.  Maybe it's a better idea to traverse your design and then query by `CASE` or `GROUP_CONCAT` in order to get a `PIVOT` or cross tabuled table.